# Xml Serializer does not deserialize to array C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, .net-4.5

Hi i am using XML serializer to deserialize incoming xml from a web service in .NET

I have created a serialization class using XSD.exe,

i have this intermittent problem where sometimes the XML does not deserialize correctly,

in the XML file there is a root element of **Result** which has a child element **Transactions**, This is a collection of multiple **Transaction** elements, however sometimes when deserialized only 1  is created even though multiple are present in the XML,

as it is intermittent my initial thoughts were that the XML was different however this is not the case.

here is my code:

**Deserialization Class**

```
public partial class Result
{
  private ResultTransaction[] transactionsField;

  /// <remarks/>
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItem("Transaction")]
   public ResultTransaction[] Transactions
   {
      get
      {
         return this.transactionsField;
      }
      set
      {
         this.transactionsField = value;
      }
   }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ResultTransaction
{

   private ResultTransactionSequence sequenceField;

   private ResultTransactionActivity activityField;

   private System.DateTime issuedField;

   private ResultTransactionUser userField;

   private string notesField;
}
```

**Code to deserialize**

```
StringReader rdr = new StringReader(xml);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
Result res = (Result)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```

**Sample XML:**

```
<Result>
  <Transactions>
    <Transaction>
      <sequence>
        <transactiontype>Customer</transactiontype>
      </sequence>
      <Customer>

      </Customer>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
      <sequence>    
        <transactiontype>Customer</transactiontype>
      </sequence>
      <Customer>
      </Customer>
    </Transaction>
 <Transactions>
</Result>
```

does anyone know why this is as its driving me crazy

Comment: So you are able to properly deserialize the XML sometimes, but not always?  Can you provide an example of the passing and failing XML or is the XML the exact same that passes and fails?

Comment: Yes sometimes it works correctly and other times it does not, the XML is exactly the same, say there are 6 transactions sometimes it will deserialize as an array of 6 and other times it will only do the first one and disregard the rest, with no pattern

Comment: the XML in the question is a basic sample, i have removed various fields to try and isolate the problem

Comment: I ran into a similar problem with the XML Serializer, what I found is that the XML serializer stops when it encounters an error while deserializing.  It doesn't warn you or anything you just get one array missing.  You'd have to look at the specific XML in each case to see if there is an error.  If the *SAME* Xml can go through and give different results that is probably a different issue. But I'd be very strict about calling XML the SAME.  Try to write an XSD to validate your XML first, it will show you where your XML is broken so you have more information.

Comment: I was hoping you was not going to say that, i asked the web service provider to provide me with an XSD file but they are unable to so it seems i must create one @thinklarge thanks for this, i assumed it was an error in XML serializer but thought that it would tell you about it

Comment: @thinklarge Is there any way to debug the deserialization, i.e step into the class and possibly see where it is falling over, i have all the just my code settings etc set correct,

Comment: Not really.  That's why I started using an XSD.  However, someone apparently caught the issue with your xml.  That ought to fix you up.